# How can arrange custom fields so they are side by side?

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, 4.7, jquery

I have a high number of 'outcomes' for a client in the format of 3 fields for each outcome as below:

'outcome words',  date identified,    date met

Problem is that custom fields are formatted as one below the other as:

- 'outcome words'
- date identified
- date met

Which means that the screen will be very deep causing the user to scroll down a lot.  What would be involved in re-formatting the screen so that these fields are all side by side?

Comment: Does the multi-record, 'Tab with table' work for this problem?

Comment: These custom fields are 'per case' so unfortunately this idea won't work as only custom fields for contacts can be mult-record.  But nice idea!

Comment: Which CMS? If Drupal have you considered webform-civicrm? Webform Layout, or 'grid' could help

Comment: It's Drupal. Thanks, I will look at webform and see if that will work - but these custom field sets are for a case so hard to see how a webform will help.

Comment: The case custom fields are formatted as a series of one row tables. You could add some jquery to move them around

Comment: @Aidan that comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Coleman - thanks for the nudge.  See below

Answer (score 4):

The case custom fields are formatted as a series of one row tables.  You could add some jQuery to move them around.

For example:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $('#Outcomes table:nth-of-type(3n+1)').each(function (index) {
    // Combine 3 rows into 1      
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
      $(this).find('td:last').after($(this).next().find('td'));
      $(this).next().remove();
    }
    // Merge tables
    if (index > 0) {
      $(this).prev().find('tr:last').after($(this).find('tr'));
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
  // Remove labels if not wanted
  $('#Outcomes td.label').remove();
});
```

You can add it to your page in various ways, but I'd create a tiny extension and drop it in there.  See also [wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Javascript+Reference](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Javascript+Reference)

Without jQuery:

[image]

With jQuery:

[image]